# Leadtools: Generarate a new tiff image by selecting 3 to 4 sections of existing tiff image

Tags: asp.net, html, html5-canvas, leadtools-sdk

We need to generate a new TIFF image by selecting 3 to 4 sections of existing tiff image using leadtools in ASP.NET.  I am lost as to were to start, can you suggest examples?

Comment: have you done anything for this ? Do some effort then post your code. don't ask us to do your work.

Answer (score 1):

If by sections you mean rectangular tiles from the original images, you can either load them using Leadtools.Codecs.RasterCodecs.Load(string fileName, LeadRect tile) or you can load the whole source image using Leadtools.Codecs.RasterCodecs.Load(string fileName) and use the RasterImage.Clone(LeadRect) method to get one or more sections from one image.

Then create a large image using RasterImage.Create() and paste the tiles on the large image using CombineFastCommand.
After that you can use Leadtools.Codecs.RasterCodecs.Save() to save the final resulting image.